# How to show one jsp page as a popup in another jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Following is my Current.jsp page code and I need to show myWindow.jsp page as pop-up after click on image whose name="ok" following is the code. Im new to jsp and java script hence unable to proceed any help would be appreciated.
Current.jsp is as follows:

```
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        MyFunction=function()
        {
        window.location.href='../../path/myWindow.jsp';
        }
        </script>
        <TABLE width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="textcopy" bgcolor="#E5E5CC"> <TBODY> <TR valign="bottom">
        <TD width="10%" class="copytable" align="right" height="30" valign="bottom">
        <DIV id="hideButton" class="hideButton">
        <input type="image" accesskey="O" border="0" name="ok" id="ok" src="images/nav/ok.gif" width="73" height="22" hspace="2" alt="OK" onmouseover="if (document.activeElement.id != this.id) {this.src='./images/nav/ok_s.gif'; }" onclick="javascript:MyFunction()" tabindex="<%= String.valueOf(tabIndex++) %>">
        </DIV></TD><TBODY></TABLE>
```

Following is the myWindow.jsp

```
 var myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "height=200", width=200");
        myWindow.document.write(<!DOCTYPE html>);
        myWindow.document.write(<html><head>
        <body><table width=100, height=100, border=0>
        <tr>
        );
        myWindow.document.write(<td>Statement Description</td>);
        myWindow.document.write(<td><input type='text' name='myFormtext' /></td>);
        myWindow.document.write( <td><DIV><input type="image" accesskey="O" border="0" name="ok"
        id="ok" src="images/nav/ok.gif" width="73" height="22" hspace="2"
        alt="OK"
        onmouseover="if (document.activeElement.id != this.id) { this.src='./images/nav/ok_s.gif'; }"
        onmouseout="if (document.activeElement.id != this.id) { this.src='./images/nav/ok.gif'; }"
        onfocus="this.src='./images/nav/ok_s.gif'"
        onblur="this.src='./images/nav/ok.gif'"
        tabindex="<%= String.valueOf(tabIndex++) %>">
        </DIV></TD>
        <TD width="10%" class="copytable" align="right" height="30"
        valign="bottom"></td>);
        myWindow.opener.document.write(
        </tr>
        </table>
        </body> </head> </html>);
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use a new Window? Whats better is to just use a modal div. For example JQuery Dialog is very easy to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Rey333. using modal div is very easy to accomplish this task.